# Store last local input file img.src URL used (not current) and use it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im a beginner at this and tried looking around for answers but couldnt find one for my problem. I have an input file field that loads eg   test.png file from local.
After that I can view the image. 
Then I want to clear the input field via button ( I did that already) but I also want an option to reload last used input file.

1. Load file eg char.png
2. Reset input file (done)
3. Load last used image via button (so I dont have to locate it again if I want to use last file) - Load last used - button

[Visualization:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLwMF.png)

HTML part:

```
<form>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="file_input">
    <button onclick="reset2($('#file_input'));event.preventDefault()">Reset file</button>
    <button onclick="reload()">Load last used</button>
</form>
```

JS part:

```
    document.getElementById('file_input').addEventListener("change", loadFile, false);
function loadFile(e) {

    var inputFile = e.target.files[0];
    console.log(inputFile);
    img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(inputFile);
    stored = window.URL.createObjectURL(inputFile);
}

//reset file input
window.reset2 = function (e) {
    e.wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
    e.unwrap();
}
function reload(){
img.src = stored;
}
```

I tried using a global variable "stored" to store current URL of selected local input image and use it in reload() function to load the last used file without having to show the path to it.

But after loading a file, then clearing the input via reset2 function when I click my "Load last" button it says its empty aka last used file doesnt load.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: I don't think this is possible because it would allow someone using script to select any file on a user's hard drive, which is a major security problem.  I believe most browsers prevent you from programmatically injecting file locations.

Comment: Im aware. I tried a a few solutions to similar problems and only way was to have the image stored in local server or outside. But in this case I tried first loading a file to img.src (which will get its URL) then saving this URL also to "stored" var so it wont get reset after I reset the <input>. I thought this way would kinda work as the URL was already previously generated and file was selected. I just want to re-use the URL later after clering it.     If this also would not work then whelp.

Comment: It wouldn't work because you can't set the file location in the dialog from within the script. Even if you save it out into a different variable, the input file element simply doesn't allow set from anywhere except the web browser's file browsing window.  Sorry.  Once it's reset, it's not re-settable without invoking the file browser again.  Fortunately, most file browsers will return to the previous location once you've selected a file the first time.